# Using swf as audio from javascript

Tags: javascript, html, audio, flash

I've been working at a startup for some time and nearly have a product ready to ship for a certain platform that's a very high quality html5 javascript game. Everything was made in html5 from using canvas and even the audio+video elements. Now after we sent in our product for review they responded by telling us that the audio wasn't finished yet on their end and to convert our audio to swf and use flash for it instead.

The problem is I'm not a flash developer, I've never touched flash and only worked in javascript and we're already behind schedule. I don't have the slightest clue how I'd go about using swf files to play audio in a non obtrusive manner for an action game. Especially since our game is no simple game with a simple sound track. There's several tracks of audio an opening video, and dozens of sound effects for weapon clashes and such.

**Is there anyone that can give me some tips or share some links on how I could go about using swf for audio for lots and lots of sounds without it making a mess of things and the dom?**

Thanks alot

Comment: Don't understand why you need to switch playing audio from HTML5 to Flash

Comment: appup encapsulator, didn't realize no audio support until too late:/

Answer (score 1):

This post should help you with calling flash functions from javascript. http://painteddigital.com/2008/calling-flash-as3-functions-from-javascript/ Pretty easy.

Playing audio from flash is very simple too. Just take a look at the documentation for the [`Sound`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Sound.html#play%28%29) class.